# Cannot connect rails and mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, connect, mysql2

So I'm trying to perform a simple database dump from the command prompt for the first time and the rails command keeps aborting with an error. This is running Ruby 2.3.0 with rails 5.0.7 and mysql 0.5.0.

```
C:\Users\MR_ra\Documents\Sites\matt_radin_cms>rails db:schema:dump --trace 
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump

rails aborted!

NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:14:in `default_query_options'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:25:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:25:in `new'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:25:in `mysql2_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:729:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:773:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:752:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:713:in `acquire_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:883:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:241:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:240:in `open'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:240:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
```

Comment: what's your OS, how did you install mysql?

Comment: Are you including `mysql2` anywhere? Is it in your `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 1):

It's looking like no Mysql installed in your machine or adapter setting is wrong.

First install mysql server in your machine.
after that install mysql2 gem by below command or adding in application gemfile

gem install mysql2

gem 'mysql2'

then do below setting for your adapter

default: &default

adapter: mysql2

username: xxxxx

password: xxxxx

host: localhost

pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

timeout: 5000

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with `mysql2` gem version, you can define the version like this

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.17'
```

then `bundle install`, it solved the problem on my hand.

The `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  username: root
  password: #=> if you use password to your local databse then use otherwise empty this
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: database_development
```